# Port field from NULLABLE to REQUIRED in BigQuery

Tags: schema, google-bigquery, data-migration

I am trying to move a BigQuery table to a new schema that has some additional new NULLABLE fields and in which a field `f` has become REQUIRED (they were NULLABLE in the old schema.)

I tried to update the table with the new schema through the command

`bq update <table> <new_schema>`

and I get the error

`BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table`

As a second attempt, I created a temporary empty table with the new field and then tried to append there the data coming from a query (SELECT * from the old table), but I get the error:

`Invalid schema update. Field f has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE`

Is there a way to do this migration easily? Of course I am fine with ignoring rows of the table where the field `f` is actually NULL. It would be cool if BigQuery could infer that from the query. I tried to do

`SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE f IS NOT NULL`

and append the result to the table with the new schema, but that doesn't work.

Comment: When you append the results of a query to a table BigQuery requires that the schema of the query be compatible with the table. REQUIRED to NULLABLE is un-compatible, and "WHERE f IS NOT NULL" doesn't change the schema of the query. Sorry I couldn't think of a solution to this problem.

Comment: @HuaZhang Thanks for your comment. Thinking about it, it makes sense that a clause in the query doesn't change the schema of the query. In fact, I can imagine cases where it would be complicated to infer the schema just from the clauses of the query. I guess the solution I have left is to write a script that reads rows from the query and push them in the table with the new schema.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use empty string where f is null.

```
CASE
    WHEN f IS NULL THEN ""
    ELSE f
END as f
```

Answer (score 0):

Use second approach - create new table and append data there.
But use `StandardSQL dialect`. It will avoid "changed mode" error.
If you are trying to insert NULL, the query would still fail, of course.